# What is the difference between overriding lifecycle methods of activity or fragment and adding a LifecycleObserver to its lifecycle object?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I was reading developer.android documents [(this page)](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/recommendations#lifecycle) and encountered this paragraph :

> Do not override lifecycle methods such as onResume in Activities or
> Fragments. Use LifecycleObserver instead. If the app needs to perform
> work when the lifecycle reaches a certain Lifecycle.State, use the
> repeatOnLifecycle API.

My question is, What is the difference between overriding lifecycle methods of an activity or fragment and adding a LifecycleObserver to its lifecycle object?

It is for making the code cleaner and nicer or are there some perfomance-related reasons or prevention of errors and bugs, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, they both work **similarly**. At least that's what I found out through digging up some articles and docs.

I always override my lifecycle methods in my Activities, and I have to tell that's not been a problem to me at all. But as I've found out, I have been doing wrong, *kind of*.

I don't want to sound noob but **I'm no expert**. I just like to read a lot. So let me share what I understand about the difference so far through my search.

They simply don't differ gigantically. Using `LifecycleObserver` instead of overriding, promotes **better separation** of concerns and **improves** code maintainability. In simple terms, they can make your code *messy*.

What do we mean by improving the maintainability? Well, improving maintainability of your code gives you benefits such as dealing with **less bugs**, separating the **lifecycle-related** **logic** from your UI components, better testing etc. Efficient code, happy coder.

So in conclusion we *should* avoid using the old lifecycle methods directly in our Activities or Fragments because they can make your code **less maintainable**. These newer techniques promote better organization and less chance of bugs in our Android app.

Hope this information is useful to you.

Answer (score -1):

I have used both, they both work similar. Callbacks are more reliable in my experience, some times onResume is not called when it should be in Activity or Fragment.

This is also an official site recommending something so not needed but according to Android, please prefer it when you have a choice. In Activity.onResume you may choose order of super.onResume and some callbacks with your code and that may cause some errors including what is current state.

With callbacks less control but things are consistently, like state. Also, callbacks can have their own things and methods independent, keeping code in separate classes and thus making some code less complex. You may reuse code with multiple things with callbacks, less so with Activity or Fragment. Overrides are older and will work on older devices though.

Like my onPause experience was with a real device, a phone I no longer have, running Android KitKat, and a Nexus 7 Grouper running Android KitKat. An observer is annoying to unregister sometimes in like my experience and overrides stay inside a class while callbacks can be global to a system. Callbacks also may stay registered without an Activity or Fragment active. I am using callback like that LifecycleObserver.